# How to validate combined values in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making a hospital app and there are `health_problems` which are composed by a `patient_id` and a `problem_type_id`.

A patient can have multiple `health_problems` but they cannot be of the same `problem_type_id`.

When I create a patient, I create its `health_problems` as nested attributes. But the validation is **not stopping** me from creating duplicated `problem_types` for one patient.

This is my HealthProblem model:

```
class HealthProblem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :problem_type
  validates :problem_type_id, uniqueness: {scope: :patient_id}
end
```

I also tried to set `problem_type_id` and `patient_id` indexes' unique, but it didn't work as expected (i couldn't add any repeated problem_type/patient even with different problem_types/patients)

---

**UPDATE:** I was adding index wrongly.
As pointed by @mmichael this is the proper way to add indexes:
`add_index :health_problems, [:patient_id, :problem_type_id], unique: true`

Now the database throws me an error that prevents it from adding duplicated problem_types for one patient. It is an advance but still not what i need.

I need this error to be shown by rails validation (in a way it could be treated properly).

---

**UPDATE 2:** It looks like a [known rails bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20676), when using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` + `validates uniqueness with scope`.

Creating unique indexes for multiple columns will prevent from adding duplicates, but - until this version of Rails (5.1) - the validation will be shown in two times: first the sql duplicate validation, then the other validations your model has.

As this can only be validated at database level, the model validation (`validates :problem_type_id, uniqueness: {scope: :patient_id}`) is not needed. Hope Rails team fix it soon.

The database error can be treated with [rescue_from](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from).

Comment: When you say you've tried adding unique indexes, have you tried `add_index :health_problems, [:patient_id, :problem_type_id], unique: true`?

Comment: @mmichael actually I was adding separated indexes (which was an error).

The way you said worked as i wanted, but it validates only in database, which returns:
"Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '6-3' for key 'index_health_problems_on_patient_id_and_problem_type_id'"

I need it to return a validation error.

Comment: Assuming you're using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in creating your HealthProblem records, there is a [known rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20676) with various workarounds. I suggest you rescue from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` from wherever you are creating your record(s). If you're doing this in a controller, take a look at [`rescue_from`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from), or you could simply wrap your record creation block in a standard `rescue`.

Comment: That's correct, i'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, it looks like a rails bug as you pointed. Great help on your answers, thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome

Answer (score 3):

I also got this problem on `Rails 5.1.5`. My solution was to use a unique database index (like @artur-haddad proposed) in combination with the models `around_save` callback. I'll try to explain my problem and solution as a short outline.

**Problem:**

```
Institution (id:integer, name:string)
    | 1
    |
    | *
WaterSupply (id:integer, meter:string, institution_id:integer)
```

So an `Institution` may have many `water_supplies` and each `WaterSupply` needs a unique `meter` reference. To edit `water_supplies` within a common form I am using

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :water_supplies, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

At this point the validation

```
validates :meter, uniqueness: {scope: :institution_id}
```

within `WaterSupply` **does not work anymore** due to a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20676).

**Solution:**

1. Add a unique database index to table `water_supplies`

   ```
   add_index :water_supplies, [:meter, :institution_id], unique: true
   ```
2. Add `around_save` model callback

   ```
   class WaterSupply < ApplicationRecord
     # Associations
     belongs_to :institution

     # Validations
     validates :institution, :meter, presence: true

     # Callbacks
     around_save :catch_uniqueness_exception

     private

     def catch_uniqueness_exception
       yield
     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
       self.errors.add(:meter, :taken)
     end
   end
   ```

That's all. Now the attribute `meter` gets an `ActiveModel::Error` on each save if it is no longer unique within the given scope and the form will display the error `already taken`.

Comment: I get 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to save the record' when i use this method

Comment: When I use this and try to create the parent with two nested records with a duplicate entry, the un-saved parent model still has an id and the persistence methods like #new_record? and #persisted? are incorrect.